# Как грамотно сделать редирект через файл hosts?

Tags: php, windows, hosts

Здравствуйте коллеги! 
Сотрудники моего предприятия зависают во вконтакте, башорге и прочих гейпорно сайтах. Просто перекрыть доступ через hosts - мне кажется не интересным. Я хочу чтобы их перенаправляло на `stackoverflow`. В теории, вроде писать нужно так (в файле hosts):

```
151.101.1.69   vk.com
151.101.1.69   *.vk.*
```

К моему сожалению, этот код просто уныло перекрывает доступ к сайту. (Я сие тестировал на разных айпишниках дома и на работе, от системы ничего не зависит).

**Вопрос:** Как правильно отредиректить юзера черех хост?

Comment: А вы пробовали писать https: //vk.com в hosts?

Comment: по разному пробовал. Результат тот же.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще проблему можно решить через сервис UserGate, а если хочется чего-то поинтереснее то arp spoofing через, например,  ettercap

```
sudo nano etc/ettercap/etter.dns

vk.com      A   ru.stackoverflow.com
```

предварительно добавив все айпишники в таргет.

Comment: а подробнее можете расписать?

Comment: UserGate: https://www.entensys.com/ru/products/usergate-proxy-and-firewall/overview . Программа ставится на хост, в рамках установки сетевых политик (например запрет или редирект запросов) справляется отлично. А dns spoofing это метод атаки, заключается в подмене данных кэша имён.